# adding an entry to multiindex dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data like this:

```
patient = "person1"
treatment = "treatment1"
doses = [dose1, dose2, dose3, ...]
```

where

```
dose = {"drug_name": "A", "drug_dose": 10}
dose2 = {"drug_name": "A", "drug_dose": 15}
dose3 = {...}
```

I need to turn this into a pandas multiindex of the following form:

```
                                "drug_name"    "drug_dose"
"patient_id"    "treatment_name"    
"person1"       "treatment1"        "A"             10
                                    "A"             15
```

And then keep on adding new entries (both new patients, and new treatments for existing patients) to the dataframe.

I first thought of making a big nested dictionary first, collecting all the data in it and then turning that into a dataframe at the end. However, that doesn't work because a person might have several courses of "treatment1" - and we can't have duplicate keys in a dict. (but we can have duplicate indices, right?)

Then I thought of making an empty multiindex dataframe and adding one entry at the time, but it proved too difficult for my pandas skills. How could this be done?

Or is there an altogether better approach that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can represent each dose as a dictionary but you need to add the patient and treatment identifier as well, after creating a data frame the patient and treatment and a unique number/identifier for each dose, can be set as index

```
import pandas as pd

patient='patient1'
treatment ="trearment1"
dose1 = {"drug_name": "A", "drug_dose": 10}
dose2 = {"drug_name": "A", "drug_dose": 15}
dose3 = {"drug_name": "B", "drug_dose": 15}

doses = [dose1,dose2,dose3]

for dose in doses:
    dose.update({'Patient':patient,'Treatment':treatment})

df = pd.DataFrame(doses).reset_index().set_index(['index','Patient','Treatment'])

print(df)
```

output will be
[image]

you can add a new row using

```
df.ix[(3,'patient2','treatment2'),["drug_name","drug_dose"]]=['B',10]
print(df)
```

df will look like:
[image]

BtW: The easiest way to input the data is if you create a comma separated values `csv` file in the following format

```
Patient,Treatment,drug_dose,drug_name
patient1,trearment1,10.0,A
.....
```

then read the csv into a dataframe using `pd.read_csv(filename)`